# Regular expression: Punctuation and greediness

Tags: python, regex

Lets say this is our text:

```
text = 'After 1992 , the winter and summer Olympics will be held two years apart , with the revised schedule beginning with the winter games in 1994 and the summer games in 1996 . ) Now , Mr. Pilson -- a former college basketball player who says a good negotiator needs `` a level of focus and intellectual attention  similar to a good athlete-s is facing the consequences of his own aggressiveness . Next month , talks will begin on two coveted CBS contracts'
print re.search(r'(\w+ |\W+ ){0,4}1992( \W+| \w+){4}', text).group(0)
```

> **Output:** After 1992 , the winter and

But this one gives me:

```
print re.search(r'(\w+ |\W+ ){0,4}1992( \W+| \w+){0,4}', text).group(0)
```

> **Output:** After 1992 ,

It seems strange for me because why the second regex is not greedy?

This one is a bit strange than others:

```
print re.search(r'(\w+ |\W+ ){0,4}summer( \W+| \w+){0,4}', text).group(0)
```

> **Output** , the winter and summer Olympics will be held

**Questions**

1- What is the difference between the first and the second one. For me, it should give the same text because the only difference is `{0,4}` and if `{4}` gives long string, `{0,4}` should give the same string because regex is greedy.

2- The problem may be related punctuation because third example works same both `{0,4}` and `{4}`..

I am confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No mystery here.

In your second example, `␣\W+` overmatched `␣,␣` (blank `␣` is also part of the `\W` class), so no subsequent matches were found for `␣\w+` against the remaining `the␣winter␣...` -- but the `{0,4}` constraint was satisfied, so no need for those further matches.  So far so good.

Coming back to your first example, the match above did not satisfy `{4}`, so the engine kept looking.  In the `␣\W+` match it backtracked the last blank `␣` so `␣\W+` only matched `␣,`, then 3 subsequent matches for `␣\w+` could be made against `␣the␣winter␣...` -- and `{4}` was satisfied.

Change your regular expression to either `([^ ]+ +){0,4}my_word( +[^ ]+){0,4}` (this maintains the spirit of your original expression, treat spaces as separators and everything else, including punctuation, as words) or, maybe better, `(\w+\W+){0,4}my_word(\W+\w+){0,4}` to isolate up to 4 actual words on either side irrespective of punctuation.

**Later,**

> Hi vladr. Regular expression that you provided is not working with
>   this text (target word is part in this text):
>
> > The city 's Department of Consumer Affairs charged Newmark & Lewis Inc. with failing to deliver on its promise of lowering prices . In a civil suit commenced in state Supreme Court in New York , the agency alleged that the consumer-electronics and appliance discount-retailing chain engaged in deceptive advertising by claiming to have '' lowered every price on every item '' as  part of an advertising campaign that began June 1 . The agency said it monitored Newmark & Lewis 's advertised prices before and after the ad campaign , and found that the prices of at least 50 different items either increased or stayed the same . In late May , Newmark & Lewis announced a plan to cut prices 5 % to 20 % and eliminate what it called a '' standard discount-retailing practice '' of negotiating individual deals with customers ."

Aha. It matched ***part*** in *De****part****ment*.

- If you only want to match whole words then use `(^|(\w+\W+){1,5})\W*my_word\W*((\W+\w+){1,5}|$)`, this should isolate the word between separators and/or line ends.
- If you want to match part in Department then use `(\w+\W+){0,5}\w*my_word\w*(\W*\w+){0,5}`

Comment: Nice one. Thanks vladr. Key point was that \W class contains whitespace. I totally forgot that.

Comment: Hi vladr. Regular expression that you provided is not working with this text (target word is `part` in this text): `deceptive advertising by claiming to have '' lowered every price on every item '' as part of an advertising campaign that began June 1`

Comment: @Thorn, it produces `on every item '' as part of an advertising campaign` over here.  Can you attach here the result of the match on your system, as well as the result of `text.encode("hex")`?

Comment: Sorry. Actually it contains `` but I remove it because of its functionality in SO. http://codepad.org/B7oce5Te

Comment: Aha. It matched `part` in `Department`.  If you only want to match whole words then use `(^\W*|\w+\W+){1,5}%s(\W+\w+|\W*$){1,5}`, this should isolate the word between separators and/or line ends.  If you want to match `part` in `Department` then use `(\w+\W*){0,5}%s(\W*\w+){0,5}`